# UPDATE with delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL programming
What I need to do is an Update where there may be records that are duplicate in the table.
The Table consists of 4 fields in the Key - PAYOFF + PRODCT + PROLIN + PROGRO
All I know about the table is that I need to change the PAYOFF from 1234567 to 7777777
If I use the below update command I can get an error 2627 if the new record exists. 
    `Update ICEP set PAYOFF = '7777777' where PAYOFF = '1234567'`

NOW comes the hard part: If the record 777777 (plus all of the other key fields exists) I need to delete the OLD 1234567 record (plus all of the other key fields). Just this one record then continue with the update.

The Table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ICEP](
[PAYOFF] [char](7) NOT NULL,
[PRODCT] [char](21) NOT NULL,
[PROLIN] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[PROGRO] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[TERRTRY] [char](3) NULL,
[STADAT] [date] NULL,
[ENDDAT] [date] NULL,
[company] [char](2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pkICEP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[company] ASC,
[PAYOFF] ASC,
[PRODCT] ASC,
[PROLIN] ASC,
[PROGRO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
       IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
       ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

This is what will work but I need it more Generic I have to do this replacement to hundreds of tables.

```
 WITH ICEP_SRC (PAYOFF, PRODCT, PROLIN, PROGRO, TERRTRY, STADAT, ENDDAT, COMPANY) AS
    ( SELECT '02WEST', PRODCT, PROLIN, PROGRO, TERRTRY, STADAT, ENDDAT, COMPANY FROM ICEP WHERE PAYOFF='COPY210' AND COMPANY='10')
   MERGE INTO ICEP
       USING ICEP_SRC 
       ON ICEP_SRC.PAYOFF=ICEP.PAYOFF
       AND ICEP_SRC.PRODCT=ICEP.PRODCT
       AND ICEP_SRC.PROLIN=ICEP.PROLIN
       AND ICEP_SRC.PROGRO=ICEP.PROGRO
       AND ICEP_SRC.COMPANY=ICEP.COMPANY
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (PAYOFF,PRODCT, PROLIN, PROGRO, TERRTRY, STADAT, ENDDAT, COMPANY)
       VALUES (ICEP_SRC.PAYOFF,ICEP_SRC.PRODCT,ICEP_SRC.PROLIN,ICEP_SRC.PROGRO,
       ICEP_SRC.TERRTRY, ICEP_SRC.STADAT, ICEP_SRC.ENDDAT,ICEP_SRC.COMPANY);

DELETE FROM ICEP
       WHERE PAYOFF='COPY210' AND COMPANY='10';
```

Comment: take a look at the `merge` statement: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/08/sql-server-merge-operations-insert-update-delete-in-single-execution/

Comment: first call `DELETE FROM ICEP WHERE PAYOFF=7777777` and then update the table

Comment: Which dbms? Tag product used!

Comment: I thought Merge was for 1 table to another, how would you do this with 1 table.

Comment: The DELETE is the record I want to Keep 7777777 I only want to update if its not there.

Comment: hundreds of tables or hundreds of records on the same table?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do it is use a transaction, where you delete first and update later. of course, you would want to use variables instead of hard coded strings.
something like this:

```
DECLARE @CorrectPayOff char(7),
        @WrongPayOff char(7)

SELECT @CorrectPayOff = '7777777',
       @WrongPayOff = '1234567'

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    -- Assuming you want to replace values only of both records exists
    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM ICEP
        WHERE PAYOFF = @CorrectPayOff
    ) AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ICEP
        WHERE PAYOFF = @WrongPayOff
    )
    BEGIN
        DELETE 
        FROM ICEP
        WHERE PAYOFF = @CorrectPayOff

        UPDATE ICEP
        SET PAYOFF = @CorrectPayOff
        WHERE PAYOFF = @WrongPayOff
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: This is what will work, but I would like it more generic.

Comment: This is an answer to your question. If you will be more specific perhaps we could help you better.

Comment: I changed the above question and documentation to try and make it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[ICEP] AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ICEP] WHERE [PAYOFF] = 123456) AS SOURCE 
on(Source.[pkICEP] = Target.[pkICEP])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET [PAYOFF] = 7777777
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN [DO SOMETHING ELSE]
```

Comment: Johnny, I have not used merge, when you update set [PAYOFF] = what record are you updating.  I want to delete the 123456 if there is a match in the pkICEP if everything is the same except for the PAYOFF.